# Show/hide all comments but 3 latest for each section

Tags: jquery

I have multiple questions on my page and each question has multiple comments. On page load I want to show the three latest comments for each question and hide the rest. Each question has a link that will show/hide all old comments.

The problem is that when showing all comments for question 1 and I click on show all for question 2, all old comments on question 1 are hidden. I want each show/hide button to only effect that question's comments.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .user-comment-box { display:none }
</style>

<div class="comment-box-container">
  <div class="comment-box"> <a class="see-more">Show all comments</a>
    <div class="user-comment-box"> 0 </div>
    <div class="user-comment-box"> 1 </div>
    <div class="user-comment-box"> 2 </div>
    <div class="user-comment-box"> 3 </div>
    <div class="user-comment-box"> 4 </div>
    <div class="user-comment-box"> 5 </div>
    <div class="user-comment-box"> 6 </div>
  </div>
</div><br />

<div class="comment-box-container">
  <div class="comment-box"> <a class="see-more">Show all comments</a>
    <div class="user-comment-box"> 0 </div>
    <div class="user-comment-box"> 1 </div>
    <div class="user-comment-box"> 2 </div>
    <div class="user-comment-box"> 3 </div>
    <div class="user-comment-box"> 4 </div>
    <div class="user-comment-box"> 5 </div>
    <div class="user-comment-box"> 6 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
    // Always show last 3 comments:
    $(".comment-box").each(function(index) {
        $(this).children(".user-comment-box").slice(-3).show();
    });

    $(".see-more").click(function(e) { // click event for load more
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this);
        $(this).siblings(".user-comment-box:hidden").show(1, function() {
            if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                link.text('Show less comments');
                $(this).addClass('showing-more')
            }
        });

        if ($('div').hasClass('showing-more')) {
            link.text('Show all comments');
            $('.showing-more').hide(1);
            $('div').removeClass("showing-more");
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5cc7qvk6/22/

Comment: don't get the problem, now each show all comment button works only for each groups

Comment: If you click on "Show all comments" for group 1 and then click on "Show all comments" for group 2 all old comments on question 1 are hidden (they should not be).

I want each show/hide link to only effect that question's comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this work you can amend the logic so that a class is toggled on the `a` element which shows the state of the child items - either shown or hidden. You can then change the link text and hide/show the child divs as needed. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".comment-box").each(function(index) {
    $(this).children(".user-comment-box").slice(-3).show();
  });

  $(".see-more").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $link = $(this);
    var $div = $link.closest('.comment-box');

    if ($link.hasClass('visible')) {
      $link.text('Show all comments');
      $div.children(".user-comment-box").slice(0, -3).slideUp()
    } else {
      $link.text('Show less comments');
      $div.children(".user-comment-box").slideDown();
    }

    $link.toggleClass('visible');
  });
});
```

```css
.user-comment-box {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment-box-container">
  <div class="comment-box">
    <a href="#" class="see-more">Show all comments</a>
    <div class="user-comment-box">0</div>
    <div class="user-comment-box">1</div>
    <div class="user-comment-box">2</div>
    <div class="user-comment-box">3</div>
    <div class="user-comment-box">4</div>
    <div class="user-comment-box">5</div>
    <div class="user-comment-box">6</div>
  </div>
</div><br />

<div class="comment-box-container">
  <div class="comment-box">
    <a href="#" class="see-more">Show all comments</a>
    <div class="user-comment-box">0</div>
    <div class="user-comment-box">1</div>
    <div class="user-comment-box">2</div>
    <div class="user-comment-box">3</div>
    <div class="user-comment-box">4</div>
    <div class="user-comment-box">5</div>
    <div class="user-comment-box">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great! Can we also add “fading”? I can fade in comments nicely using:
$div.children(".user-comment-box").show(500) 
But when I try to also fade out comments using the code below, all comments are hidden. Any suggestions also how to fix this?
using $div.children(".user-comment-box").hide(500).slice(-3).show();

Comment: Fading would be tricky, however you can easily make them slideUp/Down. I edited the answer to show you how. If you still want to use fading I'd suggest starting a new question for it

Answer (score 1):

Edited:

Try use this code instead, it's more reliable code:

```
$(function(){
    // Always show last 3 comments:
    $( ".comment-box" ).each(function( index ) {
        $(this).children(".user-comment-box").slice(-3).show();
    });

    $(".see-more").click(function(e){ // click event for load more
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this);

        if (link.hasClass('showing-more')) {
            link.siblings(".user-comment-box.extended").hide(1, function() {
                link.text('Show more comments');
                link.removeClass('showing-more');
            });
            link.siblings(".user-comment-box.extended").removeClass('extended');
        } else {
            link.siblings(".user-comment-box:hidden").addClass('extended')
            link.siblings(".user-comment-box:hidden").show(1, function() {
                link.text('Show less comments');
                link.addClass('showing-more');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g26ah977/)

Comment: Removing those lines stops the children being hidden on successive clicks: http://jsfiddle.net/5cc7qvk6/26/

Answer (score 1):

You are using a generic selector $('div') that selector hides all the div elements so you can try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/7ctuxsaa/)

```
   $(function(){

// Always show last 3 comments:
$( ".comment-box" ).each(function( index ) {
 $(this).children(".user-comment-box").slice(-3).show();
});

$(".see-more").click(function(e){ // click event for load more
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this);
    $(this).siblings(".user-comment-box:hidden").show(1, function() {
if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
        link.text('Show less comments');     
        $(this).addClass('showing-more')
}        
}); 
  console.log($(this).siblings());
if ($('div').hasClass('showing-more')) {
    link.text('Show all comments');  
    $(this).siblings('.showing-more').hide(1);
    $(this).siblings('.showing-more').removeClass("showing-more");
 //$('div').removeClass("showing-more"); this was removing the class ".showing-more" from all the divs
}

});
});
```